# LDA model returning one topic

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda

I can only get my LDA model to return the values to one topic when I specify 3 topics in n_components. Is this because it can only find one topic?

Below is the full code following https://ourcodingclub.github.io/2018/12/10/topic-modelling-python.html instructions:

```
cvec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range = (2,2), token_pattern='\w+|\$[\d\.]+|\S+')
billie_tf = cvec.fit_transform(X).toarray()
billie_featurenames = cvec.get_feature_names()

lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=3, random_state = 77)
#fit model to lyrics
lda_model.fit(billie_tf)

def display_topics(model, feature_names, no_top_words):
    topic_dict ={}
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        topic_dict['Topic %d words' % (topic_idx)] = ['{}'.format(feature_names[i])
                                                     for i in topic.argsort()[:-no_top_words - 1: -1]]
        topic_dict['Topic %d weights' % (topic_idx)] = ['{:.1f}'.format(topic[i])
                                                       for i in topic.argsort()[:-no_top_words -1 : -1]]
        return pd.DataFrame(topic_dict)

display_topics(lda_model, billie_featurenames, 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Why is the return statement inside the for loop, it causes the loop to break after the first iteration itself, resulting in just one topic to be processed.